# Bold list item for entire list

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem

How do I make it such that all text in my list are bold by default?

Is repeating the many lines of `\textbf` the only way to achieve this?

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*, parsep=10pt, font=\bfseries]

\item \textbf{List Item}
\item \textbf{List Item}
\item \textbf{List Item}
\item \textbf{List Item}
\item \textbf{List Item}

\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please edit your code to produce a MWE (minimum working example), beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`, rather than a code snippet.

Answer (score 5):

Define a new environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newenvironment{bfenumerate}[1][]
 {\begin{enumerate}[before=\bfseries,#1]}
 {\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}
This is a boldface enumerate
\begin{bfenumerate}
\item First
\item Second
\end{bfenumerate}
and this is a normal one
\begin{enumerate}
\item First
\item Second
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

You can add any `enumitem` option also to `bfenumerate`, just call it, for example, with

```
\begin{bfenumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
```

for alphabetic enumeration.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just use the font switch command inside the environment before the first item

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*, parsep=10pt, font=\bfseries]
 \bfseries
\item List Item
\item List Item
\item List Item
  \begin{enumerate}\normalfont
  \item List Item
  \end{enumerate}
\item List Item
\item List Item
\end{enumerate}
```

the `font` option is for the appearance of the label (number) for the various items.

Comment: What if I don't want sub-lists to be bold?

Comment: Just put a `\normalsize` and eventually other font switch commands right inside the sublist.

Comment: Is that the only way to do that? Will I be better of manually setting each list item to bold then?

Comment: You don't have to repeat the font command for each item. You can create your own environment for the font switch command `\newenvironemnt{boldemuerate}{\begin{enumerate}[options]\bfseries}{\end{enumerate}}` to automatise it.

Comment: your inner list begins with `enumerate` and ends with `itemize`.

Comment: How do I use \newenvironment? I got an `! Undefined control sequence.<recently read> \newenvironemnt \newenvironemnt` error.